Blend mode and shadow mode options gone in blender 4.2?
So in material settings before I updated to 4.2, I see the usual Blend mode and Shadow mode options in material settings: 
Now I see whatever this is: how do I access these options?

EEVEE comes with some changes, you should check this video from Blender official channel https://youtu.be/iwpBgtKilvw?si=JHselGjWdbixk1y2

See the Material Migration guide: https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.2/eevee_migration/#materials

hey im new to the blender but i found this one explonation
didnt rly figure out how to do it with new settings mb ull understand tho :D
check msg from Secrop: https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-blend-mode/1540117/3

I wish they didn't remove those because now it messes up the texture for the glb format that I need for programs like Gdevelop. I had to go one version back just to fix it with the blend mode 

so basicaly it says:

The ‘Blend Mode’ was replaced with a more simple ‘Render Method’. You now have only ‘Dithered’ and ‘Blended’ options.
Shading Modes
Material > Blend Mode was replaced by Material > Render Method.
Blended corresponds to the former Alpha Blend. Material > Shadow Mode was replaced by Object > Visibility > Ray Visibility > Shadow at the
object level.
A Backface Culling option for shadow and a Transparent Shadows option were added to reduce the performance impact of rendering Virtual Shadow Maps.
Shadows and surfaces with the Dithered render method behave the same as the former Alpha Hashed method. To reproduce the same behavior as the former Alpha Clip option, materials need be modified by adding a Math node with mode Greater Than.
Blended materials now have correct rendering ordering of their opaque pixels.
The Screen-Space Refraction option was renamed to Raytraced Transmission and affects all transmissive BSDF nodes (Translucent BSDF, Subsurface Scattering, Refraction BSDF, …).


Do you know if Blended mode has a performance hit, compared to Dithered, or how to find out?

Even though bpy.data.materials[n].blend_method is still accessible through code, it stays locked to 'HASHED' and can’t be changed.
Optimization sometimes causes real inconvenience.
It seems the only option is to actually adjust the material in the Shading tab.
