Material's Blend Mode setting not found in Blender 4.2
I am using Blender 4.2.0 and I am following a tutorial to create a water shader via
a Mix Shader, a Glass BSDF and a Transparent BSDF.
I would like to set the Blend Mode in Properties->Material->Settings, but it does not exist. The Render Engine is EEVEE.
Has it been removed or renamed?



https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/322198/blend-mode-and-shadow-mode-options-gone-in-blender-4-2

"Render Method: Blended" corresponds to "Blend Mode: Alpha Blend". You already have that set, so you're good.
